# react table with data from list in list in json file

Tags: reactjs, json, react-table

I am new in React development and I have a json-file like the following:

```
[
  {
    "Events": [
       {
          "Id": "12345",
          "Line": "23",
          "Error": true
       }, 
       {
          "Id": "12346",
          "Line": "1012",
          "Error": false
       }
     ]
  }
]
```

I want to show the data, inside of the "Events" in a react table.

Regarding the nested data, I have not idea how to do it.
If I change the json-file, so that I have only the data, I have in Events, I have no problem. But with the nested, it will not work and I get the data in this format an cannot change it.

I used for the following table definitions:

```
export const COLUMNS = [
  {
    header: 'Id',
    accessor: 'Events.Id'
  },
  {
    header: 'Line',
    accessor: 'Events.Line'
  },
  {
    header: 'Error',
    accessor: 'Events.Error'
  }
]
```

And to create and show the React Table:

```
import React, {useMemo} from 'react'
import { useTable } from 'react-table'
import { COLUMNS } from './patternViewColumns'
import './table.css'

//export const PatternView2 = () => {
export default function PatternView(props) {

    let Data = require('./data/data.json')

    const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
    const data = useMemo(() => Data, [])

    const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns,
        data
    })

    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
    } = tableInstance

    return (
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
            <thead>
                {
                    headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                            {
                                headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                                    <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
                                ))
                            }
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    ))
                }
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {rows.map((row) => {
                    prepareRow(row)
                    return (
                        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                            {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

Somewhere a step is missing and I can't figure it out. I tried to change the const data, so that only the Events are inside, but it was not working.

Thanks for your help

Comment: *"I get the data in this format an cannot change it."* - Sure you can.  You don't have to change the JSON file itself, but once you've read the data you can re-shape it into whatever you need.  If you just need that `Events` array then you can just use `data[0].Events` to reference just that array.

Comment: Actually so simple... I knew some small step was missing. Thank you very much! Now it is working...